# data distribution in redshift for star schema model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have big fact table 2 billions rows and 19 dimensions ( product dimension is big 450 millions, another two dimensions are 100 millions each rest small dimensions table)

Can some one help me on data distribution for this scenarios ?

Comment: more info needed - please update question with table layouts (ddl) and expected common queries. also any issues with performance if you have them.

Comment: I just want to know the generic approach

Comment: flagged as too broad